# EF Core - Design database entitiesA that belong to other entitiesA

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I design this below scenario and I'm using code first Approach :

**Organizations is possessed by other Organizations**

**Branches is possessed by other Organizations, also by other branches**

**Building is only be possessed by Branches**

---

Is this :

1 to many

or 1 to 1

or many to many

or something else ?

**Because I'm thinking of the below design ?**

*Organizations 1-n Branch*

*Branch 1-n Vehicle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent your scenary with this diagram if you choose Database First.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHTpF.png)

Comment: Thank you for the diagram. But between Organizations and Branches, is it a 1-n or 1-1 or n-n ?    Also please what tool did you use to create that diagram ?

Comment: It is n-n... I used Database Diagram of SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/create-a-new-database-diagram-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: So your diagram mean :  Branches_Possessed is a joint table between Organization and Branches?  What about Organization_Possessed, what does it do ?

Comment: It has relationship between organizations to implement "Organizations is possessed by other Organizations"